Pyinstaller --onedir add pictures
I'm trying to use pyinstaller to compile a python directory into an exe
My project directory looks like this:
Folder

main.py
otherFile.py
images (folder with png files)

I ran this command in the terminal:
Python -m PyInstaller --onedir --add-data "images/*.png:images/" main.py
When I run the resulting .exe file in terminal I get this error:

[ WARN:0@2.419] global loadsave.cpp:241 cv::findDecoder imread_('images\picture.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
App not found


[ WARN:0@2.479] global loadsave.cpp:241 cv::findDecoder imread_('images/picture.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
App not found

What should I do?
By the way I'm working on windows 11
